# how to select a single row from table, the model of which has function

Tags: html, laravel

```
class CreditRule extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array(
        'department_id',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by'
    );

    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Department');
    }
```

And my controller is

```
 $creditRules = CreditRule::get();
```

Comment: Hi Eliza, can you please give more info on what you're trying to accomplish, where you're having issues, and what you've already tried that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```
CreditRule::find(1);
```

This will retrieve the row where id=1 for model CreditRule.

Answer (score 0):

@Eliza, You can use  `where`  in your controller while accessing data from model.

Simple structure of `where` this is :

```
$creditRules = CreditRule::where('id', 1)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get model by id:

```
$element = Model::find(id)
```

Get all rows of model by matching a field:

```
$element = Model::where('field','=',$value)->get()
```

Or to get the first one only:

```
$element = Model::where('field','=',$value)->first()
```